# Formula for 3 positive real roots of cubic, avoiding imaginary parts

Tags: roots, cubics

I have a cubic equation, of which the roots are the eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix. The coefficients depend on a parameter (z), and I want to prove that one of the eigenvalues ($\lambda_2$, the second one in magnitude) is locally increasing in $z$ (around $z=0$).

The characteristic polynomial has three distinct real, positive roots. The polynomial for $z \neq 0$ has the usual form:
$-\lambda^3 + b(z)\lambda^2 + c(z)\lambda + d(z) = 0$

where $b$, $c$ and $d$ are all linearly functions of $z$.

I can analytically derive the roots for $z=0$. In that case the characteristic polynomial is:
$(m-\lambda)( d_2\lambda^2 + d_1\lambda + d_0)$

where I can solve the second part with the quadratic formula to get an analytical expression. But I want to know how the roots change with z.

I used [this formula](https://oeis.org/wiki/Cubic_formula) (see below) to obtain an analytical expression for the cubic roots. However I can not calculate the derivative of the roots with respects to z, because the quadratic root Q gives an imaginary number. This prevents *me* from differentiating the root with respect to z. From what I understand it is always the case that you need imaginary numbers to get an algebraic expression for the cubic roots,  if you have three real roots.

Anybody a suggestion how I can calculate the marginal change in one particular eigenvalue ($\lambda_2$), ie. $\frac{\partial \lambda_2}{\partial z}$ around $z=0$? As already mentioned, I do know the exact roots when $z=0$.

*To be clear, I am not interested in a numerical solution. I want an expression in terms of the parameters.*

**Formula for cubic roots:**

$a(z)x^3 + b(z)x^2 + c(z)x + d(z) = 0$

the roots are then (omitting that the coefficients depend on z):

$x = p + \sqrt[3]{q-Q}  + \sqrt[3]{q+Q}$

with $p=-b/(3a)$, $q=p^3 - (pc+d)/2a$, $r = c/(3a)$, and $Q=\sqrt{(q^2+(r-p^2)^3)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the imaginary number prevents you from differentiating, though the complex number always cancels out
Maybe you should check the [trigonometric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) cubic formula

Speaking of your topic that's interesting, why should complex number appear when we don't need them?

Looking at the formula you posted $x = p + \sqrt[3]{q+Q} + \sqrt[3]{q-Q}$, the cube root part are conjugate and we know in normal cases, conjugates can be simplified

$(q+Qi)(q-Qi) = q^2+Q^2$
$(q+Qi)+(q-Qi) = 2q$
$(q+Qi)^2+(q-Qi)^2 = 2q^2-2Q^2$
$(q+Qi)^3+(q-Qi)^3 = 2q^3-6qQ^2$
$\sqrt{q+Qi}+\sqrt{q-Qi} = \sqrt{2q±2\sqrt{q^2+Q^2}}$
$\sqrt[3]{q+Qi}+\sqrt[3]{q-Qi} = ?$

the cubic formula can't be simplified, because it's already in its simplest case

check this cubic equation $x^3-6x-6=0$, $x = \sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}$

Just like the quadratic formula makes use of the square root of unity, $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$

So the truth behind this problem is that the cubic formula makes use of the cube root of unity $\sqrt[3]{1} = 1$, $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ meaning that it would always have complex number

*In general every polynomial of degree $n$ makes use of the nth-root of unity in its formula*

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer! I could get the answers for squaring the conjugates, but I dont get the square root yet, but I am working on it. I mean I saw another with a sum of two cubic roots, $\sqrt[3]{2 + 11i} + \sqrt[3]{2-11i} = 4$. I have figured out yet how to get that

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrive at this: $\sqrt{q-Qi} + \sqrt{q+Qi}=\sqrt{2q\pm \sqrt{q^2+Q^2}}$ because I really dont get that. Or can someone give me a reference for that? I am pretty sure I also dont get what $\sqrt[3]{q-Qi} + \sqrt[3]{q+Qi}$ should yield :/

Comment: $\sqrt{q+Qi}$ splits to a complex number $a+bi$, if you square both sides, separate the $R$ and $IM$ and equate together, you'll get the expression for $a$ and $b$, but it won't work for $\sqrt[3]{q+Qi}$ only powers of $2$, when $\sqrt[n]{q+Qi}$ is added to $\sqrt[n]{q-Qi}$, the $IM$ part cancels out giving a real result

Comment: I tried the formula for $x^3 - 2x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0$. When i use the formula i get x=3.Then I try to get the other roots using$x = p + r_i*\sqrt[3]{q-Q}  + r_i* \sqrt[3]{q+Q}$ where $r_i$ is $\frac{-1\pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, but I get complex numbers then, and not the other real roots (x=2 and x=-1).

Comment: You got something like $\sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}+\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}-\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}}$, if you put the two complex cube root of unity, the complex number still cancels out so that the other roots is of the form $-(1/2)*(\sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}+\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}-\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}}) ± (1/2)*( \sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}+\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{-35}{27}-\sqrt{\frac{-4}{3}}})*\sqrt{-3}$ which are real

Comment: I get it know :-) I thought I had to multiply the conjugate cubic roots with the same root of unity, but of course the roots of unity should be used in conjugate pairs as well. Again, thanks a lot!